# Adding styles/scripts to specific page

Tags: pages, templates, page-template, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to add styles and scripts to specific template, But it's not working.

In `functions.php` I tried:

- `if( is_page_template('file.php') ){}`
- `if( is_page_template( get_template_directory() . 'file.php') ){}`
- `if( is_page_template( get_template_directory_uri() . 'file.php') ){}`

When I searched for that, Some answers suggested using `wp_reset_query();`, Before the condition, but didn't work too.

Also others suggested using the condition inside a function:

```
function test(){
    if( is_page_template( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'file.php' ) ){
        wp_enqueu_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/custom.js' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test' );
```

Nothing worked with me.

In `file.php`:

```
<?php
/* 
    Template Name: testing
*/
?>
```

I created a page and used that template.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have `wp_enqueu_script` within your function spelled wrong. It should be `wp_enqueue_script`.

Also `is_page_template()` will look for your template file as is relative to your theme directory. If file.php is in the root of your theme then it would just be `is_page_template('file.php')`. Here is the reference for that function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

Try this:

```
function test(){
    if( is_page_template( 'file.php' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/custom.js' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test' );
```